# Alpha layer bug

Tags: c#, xna, alpha, blender

I have a huge problem with alpha layer in XNA.
You can see by yourself

[image: screenshot]

I wanted to draw the leaf after the tree, but I don't know how to do that, because the leaves and the tree are in one model, composed by several meshes...

If someone could explain to me how to handle the problem, it would be perfect.

Comment: Most likely you're setting up your effect incorrectly, but there's no way to tell unless you post the code that renders the tree.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, maybe it could help someone else :

```
_graphics.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;
        for (int i = 0; i < models.Count; i++)
            if (cam.BoundingVolumeIsInView(models[i].BoundingSphere))
                models[i].Draw(cam._view, cam._projection, cam._cameraPos);
        _graphics.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

The loop here corresponds to all my model, so, you need to write

```
_graphics.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;
```

before drawing and

```
_graphics.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

after drawing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that your render target has a depth buffer, otherwise the triangles will draw in order (according to the index buffer) regardless of their positions in space, as the shader has no concept of depth or faces being in front of one another.

```
finalFrameRT = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24, 0, RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents);
```

Change Depth24 to whichever suits you best.  See: [DepthFormat Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.depthformat.aspx)

This is an excellent resource:
[What is a Depth Buffer?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976071.aspx)

Also be sure that you are using BlendState.AlphaBlend and not BlendState.Opaque as the latter will always cause pixels to be overwritten the destination.

Comment: This is clearly not the problem here.  Without a depth buffer the leaves would appear to be in the wrong order relative to other objects, but even so transparent pixels wouldn't overwrite what was behind them.

Comment: @ColeCampbell The latter comment about the BlendState was key.  Transparent pixels will absolutely overwrite what is in the RenderTarget if the BlendState is set to Opaque.  I will edit the response to clarify.

Comment: I am not sure to understand... I use BlendState.AlphaBlend yes... but for the RenderTarget, I don't understand the relation. I Use renderTarget for the water effect, for the lightning, but not for that.

Comment: @user3105143 how are you drawing your models?  I am assuming DrawUserIndexedPrimitives?

Comment: My models ? just using a model class ^^ created by myself, using the Model class that Xna proposed

Comment: @user3105143 Ah I see now.  This is essentially the same concept as my answer, but your implementation is different.  When you load a model, XNA creates a BasicEffect for it, which uses the current GraphicsDevice.  You can set DepthBufferState on the GraphicsDevice *before* you load any models, and they should behave normally.  I believe your current solution will lead to problems as your scene gets more complex.  I would need to see more of your code to understand your implementation.  By setting `_graphics.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;` meshes arent writing to depthbuffer.

Comment: Yeah it's true, it leads me to others problem, the water can pass throw my model... What part do you want to see ?